# How to use setTimeout from react-native inside a function?

Tags: react-native, expo

I would like to use "setTimeout" to react native app but I don't know why I can get an error like setTimeout is not a function.

Of course, I imported setTimeout from react-native.

This is my code below

```
import { setTimeout } from 'react-native';

handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => 
if (data !== this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
  this.setState({ lastScannedUrl: data });
  setTimeout(() => {this.checkQrUrl(data);}, 2000 )
} else if (data === this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
  return;
}
```

}

```
checkQrUrl(data) {
if (data === this.state.UniqueQrUrl) {
  this.props.onPress();
  // Alert.alert(`このQR（${data}）は、登録されているQR（${this.state.UniqueQrUrl}）と同じです`);
} else if (data !== this.state.UniqueQrUrl) {
  Alert.alert('QRコードが違います');
} else {
  Alert.alert('予期せぬ障害が発生しました。前画面に戻って再度お試しください');
}
```

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is default function from JavaScript like `alert` you do not have to explicitly import it from react-native.

remove that import and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below import from your code:

```
//    import { setTimeout } from 'react-native';


    handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => 
    if (data !== this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
      this.setState({ lastScannedUrl: data });
      setTimeout(() => {this.checkQrUrl(data);}, 2000 )
    } else if (data === this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
      return;
    }
    }

    checkQrUrl(data) {
    if (data === this.state.UniqueQrUrl) {
      this.props.onPress();
      // Alert.alert(`このQR（${data}）は、登録されているQR（${this.state.UniqueQrUrl}）と同じです`);
    } else if (data !== this.state.UniqueQrUrl) {
      Alert.alert('QRコードが違います');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('予期せぬ障害が発生しました。前画面に戻って再度お試しください');
    }
```

[setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is function from JavaScript, Its not react-native component. So if you tried to import from react-native, then you will get an error.